How to obtain a solid model from a complex shell geometry?
I am trying to create a solid out from a complex mesh of a car. I have a mesh which is paper thin and my 3D printer is unable to read it, so I would like it to have 3mm walls all over like a real shell.
The idea is to print it (resin) and adapt it onto a RC CHASSI.
I have already tried "solidify", but the model is deformed as soon as I reach 0.5mm.
Also tried to extrude every internal surface each by each but the outcome was hollow walls (unfilled), so the model is also colapsing while printing (too thin).
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.


Hello I don't think that there's any magic trick, you need to either use Solidify modifier or Extrude Faces Along Normals but in both cases you'll need to make sure that no faces are intersecting

Thanks for answering. I did extrude faces of all internal areas to increase thickness of the walls, however it was all hollow. Do you know how to extrude but filling in the geometry created?

it means that your topology is not correct, maybe share a piece of your object?

how can I send you the file?

read the instructions here: https://blend-exchange.com/ only share a part of your object
